# How can I print from a .vim file?

Tags: vim

I want to print internal variables, like `s:myvar` inside a `.vim` file. My first instinct was to use `echo s:myvar` and `:source %`, but I had no luck.

Comment: Please don't totally re-phrase your questions so that the existing answers look out-of-place. Instead, better ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

I can understand how `:echo` can cause errors (when given an invalid `{expression}`), but there's very little to make `:print` complain; it only allows 3 different `[flags]`. (And it does not output to a printer, that's `:hardcopy`!!!) *Edit: this now looks out-of-place after the question has been totally rephrased*

In any case:

- you can "slow" the output by appending `| sleep 10`
- use `:echomsg` to have the output recorded and then recall previous errors and output with `:messages`
- increase the space for errors with `:set cmdheight=5`

For a more advanced debugging solution, there's the [Decho plugin](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=120).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out `finish` was getting called before my echo messages.